# manually trigger deoplete anywhere to explore top-level names

Tags: plugins, syntax, autocomplete, neovim

I recently made the big step from Vim to NeoVim and I am setting up the powerful tool deoplete to work a bit like YouCompleteMe (since I'm used to it...)

I like to have autocompletion as I type, and I am ok with `deoplete#min_pattern_length = 2` and `deoplete#complete_method = "complete"`, but **I'd like to call `deoplete#mappings#manual_complete()` from any point (also a blank line) to see top level modules and variables for example**

At the moment, I have:
`imap <expr> <C-Space> deoplete#mappings#manual_complete()` which works nice but I have to insert at least one character.

Thank you

Comment: I spent a while trying to get this to work - disabled autocomplete, removed pattern length requirements, I even ended up finding other remappings in an attempt to get Deoplete to show up manually. It didn't, in spite of several tries and documentation cross-referencing. I swithced over to YouCompleteMe, which just worked. My point being, if you can't get it to work for your use, I highly recommend switching back to YouCompleteMe. Deoplete config is, at least in my opinion, a convoluted mess